# Regular expression for date in dd/mm/yyyy format for javascript validation

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I have to do client side validation(using javascript/JQuery) for the input value which should have date in dd/mm/yyyy format.
Please share regular expression if exist. It should validate the date is proper in all context.

Thanks in advance,
Ratnesh

Comment: Please do a bit of research, including the links in the Related section on this page (on the right).

Comment: You've shown no attempt to solve this problem yourself. We will, happily, provide help with your problems, but for the most part will not do your work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

http://blog.brijeshradhika.com/2010/10/jquery-validation-date-mmddyyyy-format.html

A lot of this in google. You should have tried to find it at least.

Comment: I searched and found similar links. I need that validation can validate if such date can really exist or not

Comment: @RatneshLal, for your own good, please avoid something like this question. It did not show your effort to solve problems and people in here do not like that. Then you will be voted down. Then you will never have good 'reputation'. Then not many people will want to help you. People here have strong willing to help if you just show some efforts.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/
```

or look at [this the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Your regex validates yyyy-mm-dd date, he is asking for the brazilian format dd/mm/yyy

Answer (score 0):

Regex will validate your format, but won't validate if date makes logic sense (leap years and stuff). That's said:

[Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)
[javascript regexp, validating date problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661117/javascript-regexp-validating-date-problem)

and numerous others...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to regular expressions you may wish to take a look at datejs

http://www.datejs.com

Using parse exact http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact

you can do things like:

```
var myDate = Date.parseExact("19/12/2004", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

And will return null, if the date cannot be parsed.

n.b. I haven't tested the code above, but it should work ok.

Comment: Hi @RatneshLal here is an example for you, it should be working ok: http://jsfiddle.net/alexkey/g4FuL/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$
```

I was looking for the same thing and got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

This expression validates days from 01 to 31, months from 01 to 12 but it accepts any number with 4 digts for year (including 0000). And it returns true for wrong dates like 31/02/2015.

Use a regex online validator [like this one](https://regex101.com/) in order to check if it suits you.