# Regex to match date of type: ddmmyyyy

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match dates of type:`ddmmyyyy`
 , like: `04072001`
So far I have this:

> `^(?:(?:31(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:290?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$`

which is almost the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877/1499705) but without the delimiters( `(\/|-|\.)` )

Comment: So why not just remove `(\/|-|\.)` from the answer to that other question? What doesn't work?

Comment: I can't match the example above(tried it in regexpal and while the answer in the link works fine for dd/mm/yyyy, when I remove (\/|-|\.), it stills doesn't match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something more simple like this:

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|31(?!(?:0[2469]|11))|30(?!02))(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([12]\d{3})$
```

It captures the day, month, year, and validates everything except for whether Feb. 29 is actually a leap year. (To do that, I'd just perform the math on the captured year/date afterwards rather than trying to write it into the expression).

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/dH8mG3

Explained:

```
- Capture the day: 01-29
    - OR 31, if not succeeded by 02, 04, 06, 09, or 11
    - OR 30, if not succeeded by 02

- Capture the month: 01-12
- Capture the year: 1000-2999 (you could narrow this down 
                               by using number ranges like
                               (1[8-9]\d{2}|20\d{2}) == 1800-2099
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is not the best tool for this job.

If at all possible, just match `^\d{8}$` (or `^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$` if your regexp engine doesn't support the `{8}` syntax) *and then* programmatically check that the date is valid.

In a bit more detail:

1. Match `^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)$` (adjust syntax as needed).
2. Extract the three matching groups and programmatically check that they constitute a valid date.

The latter requires (a) knowing the number of days in each month, and (b) knowing which years are leap years (which depends on which calendar you're using; Gregorian is the obvious choice, but think about years before it was introduced).

The resulting code will be *much* easier to read and maintain.

(Also, if you have any control over the format, consider using YYYYMMDD rather than DDMMYYYY; it sorts correctly and it's one of the formats specified by the ISO 8601 standard.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not validate dates using only RegEx. Your language probably has a built in date object with its own methods and such which you can use in conjunction with your input whose *format* you've validated with RegEx.