# Validate date in dd/mm/yyyy format using JQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, datetime

I am taking input of date of birth and date of death. Validation required

1. date of death should be more than date of birth
2. Date format to be dd/mm/yyyy
3. Dates to be less than or equal to today.

Validate doesn't work as expected and can't figure out the problem. Please help.

[Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/mundie/Tf8r5/)

JS libraries used

1. JQuery UI for Calendar/Datepicker
2. JQuery validate for form validation
3. Additional methods for validation library

   ```
   var today = new Date();
   var authorValidator = $("#itemAuthorForm").validate({
   rules : {
       dateOfBirth : {
           required : false,
           date : true,
           dateITA : true,
           dateLessThan : '#expiredDate'
       },
       expiredDate : {
           required : false,
           date : true,
           dateITA : true,
           dateGreaterThan : "#dateOfBirth"
       }
   },
   onfocusout : function(element) {
       if ($(element).val()) {
           $(element).valid();
       }
   }
   });
   var dateOptionsDOE = {
   maxDate : today,
   dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
   changeMonth : true,
   changeYear : true,
   onClose : function(selectedDate) {
       $("#dateOfBirth").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
   }
   };
   var dateOptionsDOB = {
   maxDate : today,
   dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy",
   changeMonth : true,
   changeYear : true,
   onClose : function(selectedDate) {
       $("#expiredDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
   }
    };

   jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateGreaterThan",
   function(value, element, params) {
   if ($(params).val() === "")
       return true;

   if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
       return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
   }
   return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val())
           || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val()));
           }, 'Must be greater than {0}.');
           jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateLessThan",
           function(value, element, params) {
   if ($(params).val() === "")
       return true;

   if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
       return new Date(value) < new Date($(params).val());
   }

   return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val())
           || (Number(value) < Number($(params).val()));
           }, 'Must be less than {0}.');
           $("#expiredDate").datepicker(
       $.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['en-GB'], dateOptionsDOE));
           $("#dateOfBirth").datepicker(
       $.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['en-GB'], dateOptionsDOB));
   ```

Comment: when you are writiing:
dateFormat : "dd/mm/yy" Does it  also include  "dd.mm.yy" and "dd-mm-yy" ??

Comment: I have used simplify regex: jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDateOfBirth", function(value) { return value.match(/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/); }, "Invalid Date"); month(1-12) day(1-31)  year(19xx - 20xx)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need the `date` validator. It [doesn't support dd/mm/yyyy format](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1063), and that's why you are getting "Please enter a valid date" message for input like 13/01/2014. You already have the `dateITA` validator, which uses dd/mm/yyyy format as you need.

Just like the `date` validator, your code for `dateGreaterThan` and `dateLessThan` calls `new Date` for input string and has the same issue parsing dates. You can use a function like this to parse the date:

```
function parseDMY(value) {
    var date = value.split("/");
    var d = parseInt(date[0], 10),
        m = parseInt(date[1], 10),
        y = parseInt(date[2], 10);
    return new Date(y, m - 1, d);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for spending time to read through my code.Code seems to work after incorporating your suggestions. Bingo! :)... most of my time was consumed in finding additional methods for validator and also en-GB formatting for UI widgets. I should have removed date:true rule :)

Comment: It always returns a date even if I enter an invalid date.

Comment: What if you want to parse hours and minutes?

Comment: this not work if you write 12/13/1991 this shows as a fine date when  a month 13th not exist

Comment: This function is not designed to validate the date. The OP is already using a `dateITA` validator, and this function just aids in the implementation of additional `dateGreaterThan` and `dateLessThan` validators.

Answer (score 47):

This will also checks in leap year. This is pure regex, so it's faster than any lib (also faster than moment.js). But if you gonna use a lot of dates in ur code, I do recommend to use moment.js

```
var dateRegex = /^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-.\/])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$/;

console.log(dateRegex.test('21/01/1986'));
```

[image]

[http://regexper.com/....](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E(%3F%3D%5Cd)(%3F%3A(%3F%3A31(%3F!.(%3F%3A0%3F%5B2469%5D%7C11))%7C(%3F%3A30%7C29)(%3F!.0%3F2)%7C29(%3F%3D.0%3F2.(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%3F%3A1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd)%3F(%3F%3A0%5B48%5D%7C%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D%7C%5B13579%5D%5B26%5D)%7C(%3F%3A(%3F%3A16%7C%5B2468%5D%5B048%5D%7C%5B3579%5D%5B26%5D)00)))(%3F%3A%5Cx20%7C%24))%7C(%3F%3A2%5B0-8%5D%7C1%5Cd%7C0%3F%5B1-9%5D))(%5B-.%5C%2F%5D)(%3F%3A1%5B012%5D%7C0%3F%5B1-9%5D)%5C1(%3F%3A1%5B6-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd)%3F%5Cd%5Cd(%3F%3A(%3F%3D%5Cx20%5Cd)%5Cx20%7C%24))%3F(((0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D)(%3A%5B0-5%5D%5Cd)%7B0%2C2%7D(%5Cx20%5BAP%5DM))%7C(%5B01%5D%5Cd%7C2%5B0-3%5D)(%3A%5B0-5%5D%5Cd)%7B1%2C2%7D)%3F%24%2F)

Comment: Kudos for this diagram and regex! Is it generated? Could you tell us what's the name of the tool if it is?

Comment: here:
http://regexper.com/

Comment: Is there one for mm/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: cusman, in that case i'd use moment.js

Comment: Impressive!  This even copes with the 100 and 400 year leap year changes.

Answer (score 18):

If you use the moment js library it can easily be done like this -

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validDate", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || moment(value,"DD/MM/YYYY").isValid();
    }, "Please enter a valid date in the format DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Comment: when you are validating date in ''DD/MM/YYYY"
Does it also include dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy" and dd.mm.yy ???

Comment: If you add OR, will do the trick: 
return this.optional(element) || moment(value,"DD/MM/YYYY").isValid() || moment(value,"DD-MM-YYYY").isValid();

Comment: This will fail for :  moment(1,"DD/MM/YYYY").isValid();     moment will return true .

Answer (score 10):

I encountered a similar problem in my project. After struggling a lot, I found this solution:

```
if ($.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy","17/06/2015") > $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy","20/06/2015"))
    // do something
```

You DO NOT NEED plugins like jQuery Validate or Moment.js for this issue. Hope this solution helps.

Comment: Simplest and functional solution. Thanks.

Comment: But you need JQuery UI.

Comment: Just like you've said - you don't need plugins. This simply works. If input is false, it throws exception. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

This works fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#btn_move').click( function(){
           var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
           var Val_date=$('#txt_date').val();
               if(Val_date.match(dateformat)){
              var seperator1 = Val_date.split('/');
              var seperator2 = Val_date.split('-');

              if (seperator1.length>1)
              {
                  var splitdate = Val_date.split('/');
              }
              else if (seperator2.length>1)
              {
                  var splitdate = Val_date.split('-');
              }
              var dd = parseInt(splitdate[0]);
              var mm  = parseInt(splitdate[1]);
              var yy = parseInt(splitdate[2]);
              var ListofDays = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
              if (mm==1 || mm>2)
              {
                  if (dd>ListofDays[mm-1])
                  {
                      alert('Invalid date format!');
                      return false;
                  }
              }
              if (mm==2)
              {
                  var lyear = false;
                  if ( (!(yy % 4) && yy % 100) || !(yy % 400))
                  {
                      lyear = true;
                  }
                  if ((lyear==false) && (dd>=29))
                  {
                      alert('Invalid date format!');
                      return false;
                  }
                  if ((lyear==true) && (dd>29))
                  {
                      alert('Invalid date format!');
                      return false;
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
              alert("Invalid date format!");

              return false;
          }
       });
   });
```

Comment: REF: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/easiest-way-to-validate-an-input-date-in-custom-format

Answer (score 4):

This validates dd/mm/yyy dates. 
Edit your jquery.validate.js and add these.

Reference(Regex): [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

```
dateBR: function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/.test(value);
}

messages: {
    dateBR: "Invalid date."
}

classRuleSettings: {
    dateBR: {dateBR: true}
}
```

Usage:

```
$( "#myForm" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            dateBR: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: One should not directly edit jQuery validate core files. It is dangerous

Comment: it is never a good idea to edit library files.