# Date regex of format mm/yyyy is not working

Tags: javascript, regex, date

**i am new to regex**. i am using a regex `'^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](20)?[0-9]{2})$'` to validate credit card expiry date in **MM/YYYY** format.

this is my javascript function which checks the regex and give me response in **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

```
function isValidThruDate(valid_till){

   var regex = new RegExp('^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](20)?[0-9]{2})$');
   return regex.test(valid_till);

}
```

but whenever i pass it the date, it gives me **FALSE** in return. i am unable to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: What date is not working for you? I just tried this and it works as expected. Note: this regex does not test that the date is in the future..

Comment: But.. Expiration date must be in future :D

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Is it okay if it accepts year > 2014?

Comment: You need to pass the date in as a string.. ie: isValidThruDate("11/2004");

Comment: i've fuound the problem. date which i pass after getting from input field adds a space before and after '/' sign. e.g 09 / 2015.
what should i do to deal with this space?

Comment: Replace `[- /.]` with `\s*(?:[-/.]\s*)?` - remember to double up the backslashes if you are using strings to construct regexps (using literals `/..../` is always better than using `new Regexp('...')` unless you need dynamically generated regexps)

Comment: thanks @Amadan! you saved my day.. :) answer it in answer area. so i can vote it up too.. and will be easy to find answer for others. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isValidThruDate(valid_till){

   return /^((0?[1-9]|1[012])\s*(?:[-/.]\s*)?(20)?[0-9]{2})$/.test(valid_till);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with spaces:

```
function isValidThruDate(valid_till){

   var regex = new RegExp('^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](20)?[0-9]{2})$');
   return regex.test(valid_till.trim());

}
```

Should do the trick