# Edit a regular expression

Tags: regex, date

I have some kind of problems with regular expressions,
this one checks if my date is in mm/dd/yyyy format:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/
```

I need the same one but checking if the date is like dd/mm/yyyy (european date)

I got no clue about how this stuff work, I've checked some guides but I can't figure out how to edit this one.

Any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: Is't it easier to split the string by `'/'` then check the value of each component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a careful look at your expression: you will see that it is divided into three parts: the first part `(0[1-9]|1[012])` matches months (from 01 to 12), the second part `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` matches days (from 01 to 31), while a last part `(19|20)\d\d+` matches years (from 1900 up). Finally, `[- /.]` matches your separators (`-`  or `.`) and `^` and `$` match string beginning and string end, respectively.

I want to add two more observations:

- Usually (in my experience, mainly web) the escape character (used in your expression before `.` is `\` rather than `/`
- At the end of your expression you have `(19|20)\d\d+`: this will maths `1900` but will also match 190000 (because of the + sign).

Given this, I would change your regexp as follows:

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \.](19|20)\d{2}$
```

note however that this regexp will match also non-valid dates as for example 30th of February.

If you need something more accurate have a look here: [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Take my +1 sir. Thank you for the detailed explaination

Answer (score 0):

Example for php

09-02-2015

```
/**
         * Validates the date
         * @param string $date
         * @return boolean
         */
        protected function checkDate($date)
        {
            if (preg_match('@^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$@', $date)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

for 09/02/2015

```
/**
         * Validates the date
         * @param string $date
         * @return boolean
         */
        protected function checkDate($date)
        {
            if (preg_match('@^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$@', $date)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. what does that function expects? it returns false for my date 09/02/2015

Answer (score 0):

- `^(0[1-9]|1[012])` matches the month component
- `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` matches the day of month component
- `(19|20)\d\d` matches the year component
- `[- /.]` just matches a -, space, /, or .

This means that your regex will also match e.g. 12-31/2013

I think that the `+` at the end of the regex doesn't belong there - it would allow for additional digits after the year component.

The same regex restructured to match `dd/mm/yyyy` would look like this:

`^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d$`