# Reading input matching exact date pattern YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a Java application that reads information about a new user to insert into an SQL database. When the user is to input a new user's date of birth, I want to program to be sure that the user has entered a date that is in the *exact* format YYYY-MM-DD.

I want to use the `Scanner` method `next(Pattern pattern)`, but I'm not sure exactly how to create the necessary `Pattern` for what I'm trying to achieve. Here is what I have so far:

```
String date [] = null;
    while (date == null) {
        try {
            date = userInput.next(Pattern.compile(*your suggestion here*)).split("-");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.print("Date must be in format YYYY-MM-DD: ");                
            date = null;
            userInput.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
    }
```

What should I put in *your suggestion here*?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as a date parser, not a regex.