# How to check correct date format pattern?

Tags: java, date, format

I am facing issue related to date format pattern. Suppose user gives wrong input like this `'200000-05-16'` and I have format like this `mm/dd/yyyy`. I want to check format in java class the input date is wrong.

How is it possible to do in java?

Comment: Maybe you can try to parse the input string and grab the exceptions?

Comment: Note that `mm` means **minutes**. You mean `MM/dd/yyyy` instead. `MM` means months.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is two solutions. I **recommend the second** one (the mkyong tutorial).

### **Solution 1** (Regexp)

```
String datePattern = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";

String date1 = "200000-05-16";
String date2 = "05-16-2000";

Boolean isDate1 = date1.matches(datePattern);
Boolean isDate2 = date2.matches(datePattern);

System.out.println(isDate1);
System.out.println(isDate2);
```

Output :

```
false
true
```

The pattern is not the better one because you could pass "99" as a month or a day and it will be ok. Please check this post for a good pattern : [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

### **Solution 2** (SimpleDateFormat)

This solution take a SimpleDateFormat to check if it is valid or not. 
Please check this link for a complete and great solution : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-date-is-valid-in-java/

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDate {

    public static boolean isValid(String value) {
        try {
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(value);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dd.MM.yyyy parses 10.10.08 returning 10.10.0008 / no ParseException

Comment: 2020-06-163 also pares correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse it, if it fails - the format was not correct.

Keep in mind that [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is not thread safe, so do not reuse the instance from several Threads.