# How to in input field date when use datepicker, when pres comma on presskey replaced with dot

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I use datepicker and input form for input date. Sometimes need, becouse of better speed only input numbers from keyboard without datapicker. How I can allowed on format input field date `(type=text)`, press comma and in same moment show dot in input field (replace comma with dot). This is becouse keyboard num pad just has a comma and not a dot. Now I can not pres comma. Allowed now is only dot.

script

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dokumentdatum" ).datepicker( { changeMonth: true , changeYear:   
true, yearRange:"-100:+100", dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
dayNamesMin: ["Su", "Ne", "Po", "Ut", "Sr", "Če", "Pe"],
monthNamesShort: [ "Sij", "Vel", "Ožu", "Tra", "Svi", "Lip", "Srp", "Kol", "Ruj", "Lis", "Stu", "Pro" ],
firstDay: 2, showOn: "button",  buttonText: 'Odaberi datum', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif' , 
onClose: function()
   { this.focus(); }                       
 } );

 $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');       
   });                           
 });  
</script>
```

php

```
<p><label class="field4" for "Dokumentdatum">Datum dokumenta : </label> <input type="text" id="dokumentdatum" onblur="prepisidatumdvo(this)"  name="dokumentdatum" value="'.$dokumentdatum.'" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" size="10" class="textbox-xx" ></p>
```

Comment: You could add a function to the onChange event which changes the dot into a comma.

Comment: Input comma from keyboard is blocked by datepicker. I can only press numbers and dot with left side of keyboard, and iti is slow. I need comma from right side of keyboard. And change it in this moment in dot and show dot in input field in program (like 15.12.2015).

Comment: So, the comma is blocked, but you want it unblocked, only to change the comma into a dot again?

Comment: Yes . When press comma, nothing is shown in input field. I think it is controled in datepicker.

Comment: It all depends on the format of your date. If you specify the need of a '.' then a ',' cannot be used in the date format. Why not change the validation?

Comment: Format must be like dd.mm.yy ( for example : 13.11.15 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property in maxlength not size so set maxlength=10 in your input field.I guess you also need to validate the input string with the date format . you can try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var lastValue=""
 $(function(){
     $('#dokumentdatum').on('input', function(e){
              var data;
   data=$('#dokumentdatum').val();
   var count= data.length, ml= 10,remaining= ml - count;
          if(remaining <= 0){
       return;
          }
         var str=data.replace(/\,/g,".");
      $('#dokumentdatum').val(str.replace(/\.\.+/g, '.'));
     }); 
 });
});

 function checkFormat() {
     var reg = /^(?:(?:31(\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/g;
     var txt = $('#dokumentdatum').val();
     if (reg.test(txt)) {
         document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:green'>Correct</h1>";
     } else {
         document.getElementById("mainDiv").innerHTML = "<h1 style='color:red'>Wrong</h1>";
     }
 }
</script>
<p><label class="field4" for "Dokumentdatum">Datum dokumenta : </label> <input type="text" id="dokumentdatum" onblur="checkFormat()"  name="dokumentdatum" value="" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"  class="textbox-xx" maxlength="10"></p>

<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

see here for formats:[Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Super. It works for me very well. Thank You.  I change dateFormat like "dd,mm,yy" and on close add 
`code
 
 onClose: function()
    { 
    var data;
    data=$('#dokumentdatum').val();
    var str=data.replace(/\,/g,".");
    $('#dokumentdatum').val(str.replace(/\.\.+/g, '.'));
    this.focus(); 
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is now look like this. It is important to add on close, becaouse is need when You pick date from calendar.

```
$(function() {
$( "#dokumentdatum" ).datepicker( { changeMonth: true , changeYear:  true, yearRange:"-100:+100", dateFormat: "dd,mm,yy",
dayNamesMin: ["Su", "Ne", "Po", "Ut", "Sr", "Če", "Pe"],
monthNamesShort: [ "Sij", "Vel", "Ožu", "Tra", "Svi", "Lip", "Srp", "Kol", "Ruj", "Lis", "Stu", "Pro" ],
firstDay: 2, showOn: "button",  buttonText: 'Odaberi datum', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif' , 
onClose: function()
   { 
   var data;
   data=$('#dokumentdatum').val();
   var str=data.replace(/\,/g,".");
   $('#dokumentdatum').val(str.replace(/\.\.+/g, '.'));
   this.focus(); 
   }                       
 } );

 $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');       
   });                           
 });
```