# Date regex not picking two digit dates

Tags: regex, date

I have been using below to regex patterns for dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy patterns:

```
"(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\1[0-9]{2,4}",
"(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2])\1[0-9]{2,4}"
```

I have placed these patterns in a json file. I am using tryParseExact() to parse the date. Now the problem is when i want to validate dates like:

```
6/24/2015
22.06.2014
36-35-24
```

it is picking "22.06.2014" as "2.06.2015" and "36-35-24" as "6-35-24". I don't know where i have gone wrong :(

Comment: First of all `regex` is not the right tool to validate dates.

Comment: I agree but i don't have option to change that. I have got to work with regex only. It would be really great if you could help me out :)

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy) helps

Comment: @AruneshSingh: Not working

Comment: Which language you are using? And why can't you use library to parse dates?

Comment: I am using c#. I have other things like time, unit of length, weight, etc to validate. I have placed all the patterns in json file

Answer (score 1):

You should try this regex:

```
\d{1,2}[\.\/\-]{1}\d{1,2}[\.\/\-]{1}\d{4}
```

Note that "36-35-24" it is not a valid date so it will not match.

Comment: Why it is matching `19-13-2015` it is also not valid.

Comment: @Arunesh Singh I made regex based on given examples

Comment: Given example is *wrong*. So, how can you be *right*

Comment: These are the valid date format : 6/24/2015, 22.06.2014