# How to set Ellipses for Input type date (native date picker html)

Tags: css, overflow, ellipsis

Here is the fiddle sample for reference

https://jsfiddle.net/px0g8c4s/1/

Is there a way to achieve this`?`

Comment: There is no overflow in the date input in the jsfiddle you posted, so the ellipses is not showing. If you reduce the input width the ellipses appears...

Comment: It is there in css area, last three properties are related to showing ellipses, for more clear view Updated the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/px0g8c4s/1/ check this, still it is not showing

Comment: It's showing on my screen in Safari on desktop. On mobile (Safari on iPhone) it defaults to a fixed width iOs dropdown. Seems to be browser specific.

Comment: Yes, Safari it is showing the ..., but safari does nor support native date picker,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682138/html5-date-picker-doesnt-show-on-safari
In Chrome it is not displaying the ellipses