# Coverting Date input from String format to Date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, date

I have a registration form that asks the user for their start date. I am using a MEAN Framework which means Im using AngularJs on the front end.

**What I have done so far:**

First I tried using the following code BUT it does not work on IE & FireFox.

```
<input type="date" name="startDate">
```

Then I tried the following REGEX that I found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy) SO question.

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

The works perfectly. Below is an image of how it works in my app.

[image]

**The Issue:**

When the user submits the form the data is saved in MongoDB. In the above image you can see that data is saved as a string. I want to convert it to a proper Date format so I can perform actions on it server side (Node.js) i.e filter all users who started after 2015 or left between 1999 & 2001 etc.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

Currently I am testing moment.js. Will update my question once I have a result.

Result:

I tried the following using moment.js:

```
console.log("MOMENT" + moment("1993-03-25").format());
```

The output of the following was:

```
MOMENT 1993-03-25T00:00:00+00:00
```

I am not sure whether this is the correct format to be saved in MongoDB and will it allow me to perform server side actions on it.

Comment: This is from the mongo docs `Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which results in a representable date range of about 290 millions years into the past and future.`

Answer (score 0):

You  need to convert your `moment` object to a JavaScript date before you can save it MongoDB as a date field:

```
moment("1993-03-25").toDate()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The above code outputs the following format `Thu Mar 25 1993 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)`. Is this the correct format to be saved in?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct format. It is in fact a JavaScript date object, however, Mongo knows how to handle these.