# Validating a date format string in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, date-format

I want users to be able to enter a date format string in a text box so they can specify how they want a date value to be Displayed in their  windows form

How can I validate this date format string entered in a text box  so that they can enter only a valid C# Date format

Comment: Give all the valid formats in the combo instead. Easy for user and you both

Comment: You can make use of regex

Comment: @  Mohit Shrivastava i tried it ..but it seems to be a very long list

Comment: @kashi_rock can u explain it pls

Comment: You will get all possible DateTime formats from [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) populate those values to a ComboBox as My friend Mohit suggest. so  that your users can select a format from that list

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy) post where it validates for date formats like dd/mm/yyyy,dd-mm-yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a valid date, you need date (dd), month (mm) and year(yyyy). I can give you a simple regex, for validating dates like `dd/mm/yy` or `dd.mm/yyyy`

`(dd|mm|yy{2,4}?).(dd|mm||yy{2,4}?).(dd|mm||yy{2,4}?)`

It passes for any combination of dd,mm and yyyy or yy.

It also accepts `dd.dd.mm` or anything like that. So, Make sure you check for multiple occurrences of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) and check whether the entered date time string is valid or not.

Here is the code:

```
DateTime dt;
string myDate = "2016-12-10";
bool success = DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(success);

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParse("2016-12-10", out dt));    //true
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParse("10-12-2016", out dt));    //true
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParse("2016 July, 01", out dt));    //true
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParse("July 2016 99", out dt));    //true
```

Comment: This addresses the question of validating a user-supplied _date_ but not a user-supplied date _format_.