# How I can verify Date input in HTML 5?

Tags: html, date

How I can check if the date input is in the format D/M/Y ?

This is my code :

```
<input type = "date">test</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to validate any string with javascript:

```
isValidateDate: (str) => {
  let pattern = /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/;
  return pattern.test(str);
}
```

D/M/Y is not really a standard format for date. I suggest you test with dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd. And you can find the answer here: ([Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy))

Answer (score -2):

1. The date input needs a name attribute to be able to be verified
2. You can't verify inputs in HTML, you need another language, for example php