# JavaScript Date Validation on submit

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, date

I have here my simulation of my actual code.

What I need to do is that if the date format is not valid, it should return false and will not submit.

```js
function validateDate(DateField) {
     var regDate = /^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})$/;

     if(DateField.value.length > 0) {
         if(regDate.test(DateField.value) == false) {
             alert('Date Format should be dd.mm.yyyy!');
             document.getElementById("lblTest").style.color = "red";
             return false;
         } else {
             document.getElementById("lblTest").style.color = "black"
             return true;
         }
     } else {
         document.getElementById("lblTest").style.color = "black";
         return true;
     }
 }
  
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    //condition should be here but right now I dont know what this should be
  });
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <label id="lblTest">Date</label>
    <input type="test" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" id="txtDate" onblur="validateDate(this);">
    <input type="button" id="submit" formaction="www.google.com" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, you forgot to make a question.

Comment: So the date 99-99-9999 is perfectly fine

Comment: the regex can be improved but the logic is working fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: The label should be associated with the input using a *for* attribute. The input must have a name or it won't be submitted. The date validation regular expression does not validate that it's a valid date, just that it meets a very general pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
function validateDate(DateField) {
    var regDate = /^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})$/;

    if(DateField.value.length > 0) {
        if(regDate.test(DateField.value) == false) {
            alert('Date Format should be dd.mm.yyyy!');
            document.getElementById("lblTest").style.color = "red";
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("lblTest").style.color = "black"
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("lblTest").style.color = "black";
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

here,enable or disable submit button based on date validation

Comment: this is not exactly what i wanted. but it works! thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle submit event. And if validation not pass return false:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //validate here
})
```

Comment: currently i dont know what the code should be :)

Comment: just put there 
`return validateDate(document.getElementById('txtDate'))`

Answer (score 0):

Better you use HTML5 Date type input and parse the date in format you want.. 
That would be much convenient way of doing this..

UPDATE

Here is input Box :

```
<input type="date" onBlur="fngetDate(this.value)">
```

Here is Code To Parse It:

```
    function fngetDate(val){ 
var dateEntered = new Date(val); var myFormat = dateEntered.getDate() + '.'+dateEntered.getMonth()+'.'+dateEntered.getFullYear(); alert(myFormat); }
```

Comment: if so sir, can you give me a code with html5 date input? because i tried it and i cant format the date type on dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Here is input Box :
<input type="date" onBlur="fngetDate(this.value)">

Here is Code To Parse It:

function fngetDate(val){
          var dateEntered = new Date(val); 
       
          var myFormat = dateEntered.getDate() +
               '.'+dateEntered.getMonth()+'.'+dateEntered.getFullYear(); 
                   alert(myFormat); 
      }

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but it is not working on my end. still mm.dd.yyyy is the format shown.

Answer (score 0):

If chrome is the only target browser:

Use [date type input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) `<input type="date">`

Else Use pattern `<input type="text" pattern="yourRegEx" required>`

```
<form method="post">
    <label id="lblTest">Date</label>
    <input type="date" required>
    <br>
    <label>another Date</label>
    <input type="text" required pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}" value="" id="dates_pattern0" placeholder="dd.MM.YYYY">
    <input type="text" formaction="www.google.com" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0ay8jkx4/2/

Comment: i have already tried it. but date appears in format of mm.dd.yyyy.

Comment: check the answer now..

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this but you put required on the date field.

Answer (score -1):

just do this

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    return validateDate(document.getElementById("txtDate"));
});
```

and of course you should fix your regex to:

```
^(([0-2]{0,1}[1-9]{1})|(3{0,1}[0-1]{0,1}))\.((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\.((19[0-9][0-9])|(20((0[0-9])|(1[0-7]))))$
```

Comment: can you explain your regex sir?

Comment: This returns true for '31.02.2017', so not particularly good at validating a date.