# extracting Persian data from a String

Tags: java, android, string

i want to extract this pattern from variable `String` in java (android studio) that always include this pattern but another texts are Variable and don't have same number:

" this internet will expires on 1397/7/16 22:30"

i just want extract YYYY/MM/DD pattern every time

for example give me this:  "1397/7/16"

how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a simple pattern the gets the numbers resembling a date and time, you could go with something using regular expressions with `Pattern` and `Matcher` like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern datePatt = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d{4}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2})\\s+(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,3}).*");
        Matcher matcher = datePatt.matcher("this internet will expires on 1397/7/16 22:300");
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }

}
```

It will print the expected:

```
1397/7/16
2:300
```

If you don't know how to use regular expressions, start here:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/

And you could test them here:
https://www.regexpal.com

If you ever need something more elaborate check this question:
[Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

cheers!

Comment: @Logan np! happy coding! if you like it, accept it :)

Comment: and if i want just extract time , what i must do?

Comment: use the same strategy, but now the key is using ':' as a delimiter. I'll update the answer

Comment: remember that regexp is powerful but also dangerous! Before using it in production code, make sure your regexp is matching what you have available in your texts. There will always be surprises!