# retrieving a date from a string

Tags: python, regex

im trying to retrieve a date from a string. the problem is that the pattern of this date varies a lot (string comes from an OCR reading). These are the patterns i need to identify:

- 11/11/1111 (i can get this one already)
- 11-11-1111 (i can get this one already)
- 11 11 1111 (i can get this one already)
- 11- 11- 1111
- 11  11  1111
- 11-11 1111
- 23- 10-17
- 9 06- 17

So far, the RegEx I have is a slight adaptation (it now allows spaces instead  of just - or / separating the numbers) from a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy) :

```
match_date=re.search(r'(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.| )(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.| )(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.| )(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})',line)
```

Is there a way of building a regex for such a "fluid" date structure?

Comment: [`\d{1,2}[/ -] ?\d{2}[/ -] ?\d{2}(?:\d{2})?`](https://regex101.com/r/2uc9X6/1)? No need to overcomplicate the pattern if you don't need it.

Comment: How about `\d{1,2}\D{1,4}\d{2}\D{1,4}\d{2}(?:\d{2})?`?

Comment: You are very right, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: `\b(?:\d{1,2}[- /]\s?){2}(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b` or `^(?:\d{1,2}[- /]\s?){2}(?:\d{4}|\d{2})$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/frCGL6/3)

Comment: Matches `1$0%11`

Comment: @ctwheels Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for

```
\b\d{1,2}[- /]+\d{1,2}[- /]+\d{2,4}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0NAsqp/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I know regex is a better answer because with one line you can match all possibilities but I prefer convert to datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
string = "11- 11- 1111"

for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%d', '%d- %m- %Y', '%d %m %Y', '%d- %m- %y'):
    try:
       datetime_object = datetime.strptime(string, '%d- %m- %y')
...
```