# What is the regex ?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to implement regex in Javascript to compare if my string matches the following pattern -

```
<digit><digit>/<digit><digit>/<digit><digit><digit><digit>
```

This is similar to the DD/MM/YYYY format. But I don't want any date specific validations. I just want to check if the string contains digits as per the given pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy      Check this.

Comment: @AbhisekRoy - This doesn't solve my issue.  I am not looking for a date validation.

Comment: Try this `/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/g`

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/NhweMb/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
re = new RegExp(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/);

"21/02/2017".match(re) /* ["21/02/2018", index: 0, input: "21/02/2018"] */
"21/2/2017".match(re)  /* null */
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexei Danchenkov makes good answer, but maybe you also want additional checks for start and the end of the string:

```js
re = new RegExp(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/);

// examples
console.log("21/02/2017".match(re)); /* ["21/02/2018", index: 0, input: "21/02/2018"] */
console.log("21/2/2017".match(re));  /* null */
console.log("21/02/20171".match(re)); /* null */
console.log("21/02/2017 ".match(re)); /* null */
console.log("+21/02/2017".match(re)); /* null */
```