# Isolating parts of strings that are in a date format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting information from a website that has no API or anything. I've got the login and retrieve HTML part working and I've got a system that finds the right `<div>` that will contain the information I need. But I need to remove all the information that isn't in the format "DD/MM/YYYY". So I need to remove all the parts of this string that aren't in that format. Here's an example of the returned `<div>`:

```
<div id="wkDrop">
    <div  name="weekstarts" id="2018_29">Week 29-16/07/2018</div>
    <div style="display:none" name="weekstarts" id="2018_30">Week 30-23/07/2018</div>
</div>
```

The parts that will change each week are the id="YYYY_WW" and Week WW-DD/MM/YYYY. So from the above example, I'm after two dates: 16/07/2018 and 23/07/2018.

Please bear in mind that there could be between 1 and 4 dates within this `<div>`  so it won't always be two weeks that I need to extract.

I would also ideally have each date retrieved printed on a new line.

Any ideas how I'd go about this?

Thanks in advance for any replies :)

Comment: Since all dates are in the same format, you can use regular expressiosn

Comment: I would **highly recommend** you **not** to use a regular expression. Parse the HTML first using `bs4` (or similar) and then extract the dates using a simple string manipulation (they have a single format) it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *regular expression* (in Python module `re` - the [documentation is here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)) for retrieving the dates. The explanation for this regular expression can be [found here](https://regex101.com/r/CaJKJS/1).

```
data = """
<div id="wkDrop">
    <div  name="weekstarts" id="2018_29">Week 29-16/07/2018</div>
    <div style="display:none" name="weekstarts" id="2018_30">Week 30-23/07/2018</div>
</div>"""

import re

for dates in re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', data):
    print(dates)
```

Prints:

```
16/07/2018
23/07/2018
```

Comment: @Joe no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say first you should look into using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) to remove the `div` tags and extract the data. Then, you could use `split("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$")`.

` to split the string into an array of strings that follow the regular expression:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$
```

To extract dates in that format ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy))

Answer (score 0):

how about [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
import re

str1 = '<div id="wkDrop"><div  name="weekstarts" id="2018_29">Week 29-16/07/2018</div><div style="display:none" name="weekstarts" id="2018_30">Week 30-23/07/2018</div></div>'

match=re.findall('(\d+/\d+/\d+)',str1)
```

**Output:**

```
['16/07/2018', '23/07/2018']
```