# JQuery date validation for valid date and in MM/DD/YYYY format only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have input type="text" and I am looking for some jquery validation. The validation should check for date in the format MM/DD/YYYY and it should also check if its a valid date. If its not a valid date or format then it should clear the input textbox. The validation should be checked on typing in the textbox and also on copy pasting in the input box.

Comment: And what you have so far? Please post the key parts of your code on your question.

Comment: This is what I have
<input name="txtDate"  id="txtDate' type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>

Comment: Why do you need jquery for this? Take a look at regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773444/2291510

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

try this out, if this works for you.

[example](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-date-validation.php)

BTW i was wondering if wanna use

```
<input type="date">
```