# RegEx for matching yyyy-mm-dd and mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: regex, validation

I need a pattern that accepts mm/dd/yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd formats. I will put it inside `Validators.pattern()` as parameter.

Inputs such as 10/20/2019 or 2019-10-20 are valid.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: why is this no effort? I'm complete newbie on regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx might help you to do so:

```
(([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+))|(([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+))
```

If you wish, you can add additional boundaries to it, such as [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/0WcRPo/1):

```
(([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}))|(([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2}))
```

which has quantifier boundaries. Also, I have added capturing groups such that you can call any part of the date that you wish, together or separately.

[image]

You can reduce the boundaries also if it is not necessary.