# Extract date from strings that contains names+dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, extract

I need to extract the dates from a series of strings like this:

```
'MIHAI MĂD2Ă3.07.1958'
```

or

```
'CLAUDIU-MIHAI17.12.1999'
```

How to do this?

Tried this:

```
for index,row in DF.iterrows():
    try:
        if math.isnan(row['Data_Nasterii']):
            match = re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', row['Prenume'])
            date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d.%m.%Y').date()
            s = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d'), '%d-%m-%Y')
            row['Data_Nasterii'] = s
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Comment: what have you tried? have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: `.` doesnt mean the cahracter dot, it means any character and needs to be escaped. try this: `r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` (dot) in regex doesn't mean the character dot, it means "anything" and needs to be escaped (`\`) to be an actual dot. 
other than that your first group is `\d{2}` but some of your dates have a single digit day. 
I would use the following:

```
re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', row['Prenume'])
```

which means at least one number followed by a dot followed by at least one number.....
if you have some mixed characters in your day you can try the following (sub par) solution:

```
''.join(re.search(r'(\d*)(?:[^0-9\.]*)(\d*\.\d+\.\d+)', row['Prenume']).groups())
```

this will filter out up to one block in your "day", its not pretty but it works(and returns a string)

Comment: Then, you can check my solution.

Comment: @Nullman Thank you so much! Only one question. For this example : 'MIHAI MĂD2Ă3.07.1958' it takes '3.07.1958' BUT it should be '23.07.1958'. The '2' digit is inside the name

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str` accessor along with a regex:

```
DF['Prenume'].str.extract(r'\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `dot (.)` as `\.` or you can use it inside a character class - "`[.]`". It is a meta character in regex, which matches any character. If you need to validate more [you can refer this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

eg: `r'[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{4}' or r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}'`

```
text = 'CLAUDIU-MIHAI17.12.1999'
pattern = r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}'

if re.search(pattern, text):
    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another good solution could be using [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser as dparser

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['MIHAI MĂD2Ă3.07.1958',
                         'CLAUDIU-MIHAI17.12.1999']})

df['userdate'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: dparser.parse(x.encode('ascii',errors='ignore'),fuzzy=True))
```

**output**

```
                       A    userdate
0   MIHAI MĂD2Ă3.07.1958    1958-07-23
1   CLAUDIU-MIHAI17.12.1999 1999-12-17
```

Comment: thank you! Can I apply this on a single value not on a column?

Comment: Of course. `s1 = 'asd 03.12.1999'`, then `print(dparser.parse(s1,fuzzy=True))` and you get `1999-03-12 00:00:00`.