# How to capture a Date from a String?

Tags: java, regex, datetime

I have a String variable like that `"/etc/opt/eset/esets/license/esets_abd9c6.lic: ESET File Security, 2019-07-29 00:00:00, Mynet"` and I need to capture the date value from that field, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
String string = "/etc/opt/eset/esets/license/esets_abd9c6.lic: ESET File Security, 2019-07-29 00:00:00, Mynet";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
Date tempDate = null;
if(m.find())
{
    tempDate = format.parse(m.group());
}
System.out.println("" + tempDate);
```

Is there any regex pattern for capturing a date value from a String vaiable?

Comment: String will be going to same right?

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *date* string, you can use:

```
\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GdlzRP/1/) and note that you need two backslashes in `Java` (hence `...\\b\\d{4}...`)

---

This is

```
\b     # word boundary
\d{4}- # four digits and a "-"
\d{2}-
\d{2}
\b
```