# How to search/extract patterns in a string?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a pattern I want to search for in my message. 
The patterns are:

```
1. "aaa-b3-c"
2. "a3-b6-c"
3. "aaaa-bb-c"
```

I know how to search for one of the patterns, but how do I search for all 3?

Also, how do you identify and extract dates in this format: 5/21 or 5/21/2019.

```py
found = re.findall(r'.{3}-.{2}-.{1}', message)
```

Comment: Are a, b and c an example or should they be matches exactly?

Comment: Example. They could contain numbers too.

Comment: So like https://regex101.com/r/YnHSbo/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
found = re.findall(r'a{2,4}-b{2}-c', message)
```

Comment: I was too late :-/

Answer (score 0):

The first part could be a quantifier `{2,4}` instead of 3. The dot matches any character except a newline, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` will match a upper or lowercase char a-z or a digit:

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l1I0Nu/1)

You could add word boundaries `\b` or anchors `^` and `$` on either side if the characters should not be part of a longer word.

For the second pattern you could also use `\d` with a quantifier to match a digit and an optional patter to match the part with / and 4 digits:

```
\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:/\d{4})?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpW9nK/1)

Note that the format does not validate a date itself. Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy) can help you creating / customize a more specific date format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
a{2,4}-bb-c
```

as a pattern.

---

Now you need to check the match for truthiness:

```
match = re.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    # do sth. here
```

As from `Python 3.8` you can use the `walrus` operator as in

```
if (match := re.search(pattern, string)) is not None:
    # do sth. here
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
re.findall(r'a.*-b.*-c',message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might just want to write three expressions, and swipe our inputs from left to right just to be safe and connect them using logical ORs and in case we had more patterns we can simply add to it, similar to:

```
([a-z]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+)
([a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z])
([a-z]+-[a-z]+-[a-z])
```

which would add to:

```
([a-z]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+)|([a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z])|([a-z]+-[a-z]+-[a-z])
```

Then, we might want to bound it with start and end chars:

```
^([a-z]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+)$|^([a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z])$|^([a-z]+-[a-z]+-[a-z])$
```

or

```
^(([a-z]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+)|([a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z])|([a-z]+-[a-z]+-[a-z]))$
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/E8SNb5/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]