# Extracting a particular data from a CSV file in c++

Tags: c++, csv

I have written a program to read a CSV file but I'm having some trouble in extracting data from that CSV file in c++. I want to count the no. of columns starting from the 5th column in the 1st row until the last column of the 1st row of the CSV file. I have written the following code to read a CVS file, but I am not sure how shall I count the no. of columns as I have mentioned before.
Will appreciate it if anyone could please tell me how shall I go about it?

```
char* substring(char* source, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
int size = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
char* s = new char[size+1];
strncpy(s, source + startIndex, size); //you can read the documentation of strncpy online
s[size]  = '\0'; //make it null-terminated
return s;
}

char** readCSV(const char* csvFileName, int& csvLineCount)
{
ifstream fin(csvFileName);
if (!fin)
{
    return nullptr;
}
csvLineCount = 0;
char line[1024];
while(fin.getline(line, 1024))
{
    csvLineCount++;
};
char **lines = new char*[csvLineCount];
fin.clear();
fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
for (int i=0; i<csvLineCount; i++)
{
    fin.getline(line, 1024);
    lines[i] = new char[strlen(line)+1];
    strcpy(lines[i], line);

};
fin.close();
return lines;
}
```

I have attached a few lines from the CSV file:-

Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20,
,Afghanistan,33.0,65.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
,Albania,41.1533,20.1683,0,0,0,0

What I need is, in the 1st row, the number of dates after Long.

Comment: What is the csv file containing exactly? (At least 6 colums and a few rows would be helpful) What OS are you using, since they differ in the seperator bit etc.)

Comment: @Ivanovic I have attached a couple of lines from my CSV file for your reference:)

Comment: Thanks for the attachment. Its name is "comma separated values" (csv) but yeah, its not standardized. (just because of a;b;c;.. in one answer). 
My first idea would be using regex (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) but you seem to already have your answer that doesn't achieve what you asked for if I understood you right.

If you give me a heads up I will explain you a few easy ways to handle the csv stuff tonight, not that complicated

Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Comment: Yeah bro, it's kinda tricky these things. I am still a bit lost, it would be great if you could share with me some insights about CSV file handling, thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to search for the seperator substring within your line (normally it is ';').
If you print out your lines it should look like this:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h
```

There are several ways to achieve what you want, I would look for a strip or split upon character function. Something along the example below should work. If you use std you can go with str.IndexOf instead of a loop.

```
int rows(char* line,char seperator, int count) {
unsigned length = strlen(line);
for (int i=pos; i<length;i++){
  if(strcmp(line[i],seperator)) break;
}
count++;
if (i<length-1) return rows(substring(line,i,length-i),seperator,count);
else return count;
}
```

The recursion can obviously be replaced by one loop ;)

```
int countSign(char* line, char* sign){
  unsigned l = strlen(line);
  int count = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < l; i++) {
    if(strcmp(line[i],sign)) count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have written the following but, I am getting an error (No matching function for call to strcmp) Could you please let me know what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> I have attached a few lines from the CSV file:-
>   Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20, ,Afghanistan,33.0,65.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ,Albania,41.1533,20.1683,0,0,0,0
>
> What I need is, in the 1st row, the number of dates after Long.

Yeah, not that difficult - that's how I would do it:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

#define FILENAME "test.csv" //Your filename as Macro 
//(The compiler just sees text.csv instead of FILENAME)



void read(){
std::string n;

//date format pattern %m/%dd/%YY
std::regex pattern1("\\b\\d{1}[/]\\d{2}[/]\\d{2}\\b");
//date format pattern %mm/%dd/%YY
std::regex pattern2("\\b\\d{2}[/]\\d{2}[/]\\d{2}\\b");
std::smatch result1, result2;

std::ifstream file(FILENAME, std::ios::in);
    if ( ! file.is_open() )
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open file!" << '\n';
    }

    do{
            getline(file,n,',');
            //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
            if(std::regex_search(n,result1,pattern1))
                    std::cout << result1.str(1) << n <<  std::endl;
            if(std::regex_search(n,result2,pattern2))
                    std::cout << result2.str(1) << n <<  std::endl;
    }
    while(!file.eof());
    file.close();
}

int main ()
{
    read();
    return 0;
}
```

The file test.csv contains the following for testing:

```csv
    Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/22/20,1/23/20,1/24/20, ,Afghanistan,33.0,65.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ,Albania,41.1533,20.1683,0,0,0,0 
    Province/State,Country/Region,Lat,Long,1/25/20,12/26/20,1/27/20, ,Bfghanistan,33.0,65.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ,Blbania,41.1533,20.1683,0,0,0,0
```

It actually is pretty simple:

1. `getline` takes the open file and "escapes" at a so called escape-charachter, 
   in your case a comma ','.
   *(That is the very best way I found in reading csv - you can replace it with whatever you want, for example: ';' or ' ' or '...' - guess you get the drill)*
2. After this you got all data nicely separated underneath one another without a comma.
3. Now you can "filter" out what you need. I use regex - but use what ever you want. 
   *(Just fyi: For c++ tagged questions you shouldn't use c-style like strncpy..)*
4. I gave you an example for 1.23.20 (m/dd/yy) and to make it simple if your file contains a november or december like 12.22.20 (mm/dd/yy) to make
   the regex pattern more easy to read/understand in 2 lines.

you can/may have to expand the regex pattern if the data somehow matches 
your date format in the file, really good explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26972181/12078969) and not as complicated as it looks.

5. From that point you can put all the printed stuff f.e. in a vector *(some more convenient array)* to handle and/or pass/return data - that's up to you.

If you need more explaining I am happy to help you out and/or expand this example, just leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Appreciate it!