# What refactoring should I apply on this email validation regex?

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube, stack-overflow

Sonarqube is warning me that my Java regex reported down below for email validation should be refactored because "this repetition can lead to a stack overflow for large inputs":

`"^(?=.{1,64}@)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"` 
Plus, they're emphasizing on this part in particular:

`(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*`

It works perfectly fine in my program, it accepts emails with this kind of format:

```
username@domain.com
user.name@domain.com
user-name@domain.com
username@domain.co.in
user_name@domain.com
```

Still, I would like to fix this issue.

I am not able to understand what I should do to fix it tho, is there a way to modify this regex while keeping the same meaning?

Comment: It seems using possesive quantifiers may help https://www.sonarsource.com/blog/crafting-regexes-to-avoid-stack-overflows/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SonarQube showing Regular expression Denial of Service (ReDoS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478960/sonarqube-showing-regular-expression-denial-of-service-redos)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this regex is not prone to [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Either ignore the warning, or [do the right thing and not use regex altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/q/624581).