# FORM : checking in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 fields, the first field is named `name` and the second `dateofbirth`. I would like to improve the validation mostly on my field `dateofbirth`. I would like to use a simple code for beginner.

the rule, the user can enter a date bigger than -> `01-01-1900`, if the date is smaller, an error message must appear.

```js
function validation()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var dateofbirth = document.getElementById('dateofbirth').value;

    if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById('nameError').innerHTML = " ** the name field is empty ! ";
         return false;
    }

    if(name.length < 2){
        document.getElementById('nameError').innerHTML = " ** min 2 characters ! ";
        return false;
    }

    if(dateofbirth == ""){
        document.getElementById('dateofbirthError').innerHTML = " ** the date field is empty ! ";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
<br>
<label>Name : </label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<br>
<span id="nameError"></span>
<br>
<label>Date of birth : </label>
<br>
<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
<br>
<span id="dateofbirthError"></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we can use customized function or date pattern. Below code is customized function as per your requirement please change it.

```
function validation()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var dateofbirth = document.getElementById('dateofbirth').value;

    if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById('nameError').innerHTML = " ** the name field is empty ! ";
         return false;
    }

    if(name.length < 2){
        document.getElementById('nameError').innerHTML = " ** min 2 characters ! ";
        return false;
    }

    if(!isValidDate(dateofbirth)){
        document.getElementById('dateofbirthError').innerHTML = " ** the date field is empty ! ";
        return false;
    }
}


function isValidDate(str) {
    var getvalue = str.split('-');
    var day = getvalue[2];
    var month = getvalue[1];
    var year = getvalue[0];
    if(year < 1900 || year > 2100){
    return false;
    }
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) { 
      return false;
     }
     if (day < 1 &|| day > 31) {
      return false;
     }
     if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) && day==31) {
      return false;
     }
     if (month == 2) { // check for february 29th
      var isleap = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
      if (day>29 || (day==29 && !isleap)) {
       return false;
     }
     }
     else{
     return true;

     }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I am beginner, I don't understand how to adapt this? I am lost...

Comment: there is small change in I made Please update the code

Comment: Thats fine no problem!! just copy paste as it is and it will work

Comment: If I type the date 01-01-1000 it passes normally it should block

Comment: replace this code if(year < 1900 && year > 2100){ to if(year < 1900 || year > 2100){

Comment: Yeess ! Thank you very much, the problem is the condition. Sorry, thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since `dateofbirth.value` is in a fixed-length format, you can just remove the hyphens (`-`), convert to number, and compare to `19000101`:

```js
function validation()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var dateofbirth = document.getElementById('dateofbirth').value;

    if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById('nameError').innerHTML = " ** the name field is empty ! ";
         return false;
    }

    if(name.length < 2){
        document.getElementById('nameError').innerHTML = " ** min 2 characters ! ";
        return false;
    }

    if(dateofbirth == ""){
        document.getElementById('dateofbirthError').innerHTML = " ** the date field is empty ! ";
        return false;
    }
    if(+dateofbirth.replace(/-/g, '') < 19000101){
        document.getElementById('dateofbirthError').innerHTML = " ** the date is invalid ! ";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validation()" >
<br>
<label>Name : </label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<br>
<span id="nameError"></span>
<br>
<label>Date of birth : </label>
<br>
<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
<br>
<span id="dateofbirthError"></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Comment: @alain Because that's the number representation of `01-01-1900` in `YYYYMMDD` format in which `dateofbirth.value` is

Answer (score 0):

Just use attribute [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) and [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#min) for date to validate via browser.

```html
<form action="#">
  <label>Name : </label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern=".{2,}" title="Min length is 2">
  <br>
  <label>Date of birth : </label>
  <br>
  <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" min="1900-01-01">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Note that `date` type for input not working in desktop Safari and IE. You can make extra validator with regexp like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877/13525274). Or set date pattern and check in js for `new Date(input) > new Date(1900, 00)`