# Match multiple line text (from 1 to n lines) until certain new line regex

Tags: regex

I created regex for matching such pattern:

```
<some text>
yyyy.MM.dd SOME TEXT decimal decimal
yyy.MM.dd
some sentence
some sentence
some sentence (it can have from 1 to n lines of comments) but  the last line that does not start with yyyy.MM.dd SOME TEXT decimal decimal)
yyyy.MM.dd SOME TEXT decimal decimal
yyy.MM.dd
some sentence
some sentence
some sentence
...
<some text>
```

The regex:

```
((\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s([a-zA-Z\s]{0,})\s(\-{0,1}((\d{1}\,\d{2})|(\d{1,}\ \d{3}\,\d{2})))\s(\-{0,1}((\d{1}\,\d{2})|(\d{1,}\ \d{3}\,\d{2}))\s)(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}))
```

Which matches only first 2 lines. I can't match multiline sentences until next `yyyy.MM.dd SOME TEXT decimal decimal` (exclusively)

This is the test data for matching:

```
2020.11.01 SOME TEXT -17,30 83 016,86
2020.10.30
Some text that should be
matched 20.01.2020 as
multiline text
until now
2020.11.01 SOME TEXT -27,30 81 016,86
2020.10.30
Some text that should be
matched 20.01.2020 as
multiline text
until now
...
```

it should match like this:

1.

```
2020.11.01 SOME TEXT -17,30 83 016,86
2020.10.30
Some text that should be
matched 20.01.2020 as
multiline text
until now
```

2. 

```
2020.11.01 SOME TEXT -27,30 81 016,86
2020.10.30
Some text that should be
matched 20.01.2020 as
multiline text
until now
```

For me it matches like this:

1.

```
2020.11.01 SOME TEXT -17,30 83 016,86
2020.10.30
```

2. 

```
2020.11.01 SOME TEXT -27,30 81 016,86
2020.10.30
```

How can I match from 1 to many multiline lines WITHOUT 'yyyy.MM.dd SOME TEXT decimal decimal' on the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example data, you can match the first 2 lines with a date like pattern, followed by all the lines that do not start with a datelike pattern.

**Note** that `\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}` does not validate a date itself. To get a more precise match, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy) has more detailed examples.

```php
^\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} .*\r?\n\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OcIEij/1)

Or if you first want to match all lines that start with a datelike pattern incase of 1 or more, followed with lines that do not:

```php
^\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \S.*(?:\r?\n\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b.*)+(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \S.*` match a datelike pattern followed by a space, at least a non whitespace char (For `SOME TEXT` in the example) and the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b.*)+` Repeat 1+ times matches lines that start with a datelike pattern
- `(?:` Non capture group *(to repeat as a whole)*

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b)` Assert not a datelike format directly to the right
  - `.*` If the previous assertion it true, match the whole line
- `)*` Optionally repeat all lines that do not start with a datelike pattern *(If there should be at least 1 line, change the quantifier to `+`)*

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7q7eUO/1)