# How to have date in mm/dd/yyyy format on typing in date picker textfield in nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I implemented a date picker in a nuxtjs with the vuetify app. It's working fine when selecting any date from the calendar. I need to enable the same functionality while typing also. If I am typing like 12122021, it should be formatted to 12/12/2021 on typing itself. Here is what I have tried so far.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fms71e?file=pages/index.vue

I am getting an undefined error when I lose focus. How can I implement the functionality?

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with Nuxt or Vue, but you should be able to simply attach a function to the onChange event of your input field. When doing so, it will trigger a function and then properly validate and format the results using something like Regex.

Here's a post to show you the Regex. There may be other plugins like day.js or moment.js that can help as well. But hopefully this makes sense!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-formats-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mmm-yyyy

Comment: Thanks for this but I am not able to figure it out in coding :(

Comment: Please do not recommend Moment.js, it's deprecated.

Comment: @kissu can you show me the right way?

Comment: I use a couple js funcs to format dates, I have them in a custom lib that I add as a mixin. Also made a custom v-date-picker component to avoid configuring it everytime. I can made an example codesandbox for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this codesandbox I made, I'm not using Nuxt but you can make yourself an idea to implement it on your project: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70724804-sryk8?file=/src/components/custom/CustomDatePicker.vue

This is a custom date picker component that I made for one of my projects. You can customize it to your needs but the component already come with multiple customization options that you can enable/modify through `props`.

The date picker can display dates in 3 formats. It use `vue-the-mask` library to control manual date inputs and some auxiliary functions to control date convertions that I import as a mixin.

1. dd/MM/yyyy
2. MM/dd/yyyy (Using "month-first" prop)
3. yyyy/MM (using "month" prop)

Regardless of the format you choose to display to the end user, the custom date picker will always work internally with `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM` date format

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, brother. Sorry for the late reply but you saved my life <3